# Отрисовка множества различных примитивов openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, шейдеры

Всем привет. Научился рисовать объекты (квадраты) по клику мыши (клик - центр объекта). Использую ортогональную проекцию, координаты высчитываются в пикселях.

Но теперь нужно добавить к этим объектам, а вернее наложить поверх этого, сетку. Сетку я генерирую в зависимости от ширины и высоты окна, завожу 2 массива, 2 VAO и 2 VBO. Настраиваю всё, связываю. Затем в игровом цикле отрисовываю сначала горизонтальные линии, потом вертикальные:
[image: Сетка]

Я был уверен, что если я сначала сделаю bind VAO для сетки, а вернее сначала для вертикальных линий, затем для горизонтальных, отрисую их, а уже ниже сделаю bind VAO для квадратов - то всё будет пучком. Но нет, отрисовывается только сетка. 
Я думаю, что проблема в том, что в игровом цикле, где идёт орисовка сетки, в шейдер передаётся позиция моих линий, а затем уже я пытаюсь динамически обновлять массив в квадратами, передавая их в тот же шейдер, потому они и не рисуются.

При этом, квадраты не отображаются даже если просто инициализировать перед циклом буфферы для сетки. Иначе говоря, если я создаю VAO и VBO, настраиваю их под мои линии, а затем пускаю цикл, где рисую квадраты - квадратов уже не видно. Почему такое происходит? Ведь я делаю bind того VAO, который мне нужен.

Вот код инициализации квадратов:

```
void initBuffers()
{
GLsizeiptr vertexBufferSize = maxNumberOfPrimitives * 3 * 5 * 
sizeof(GLfloat);
GLsizeiptr elementBufferSize = 3 * sizeof(GLfloat);

glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferSize, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);


GLuint indices[] = {
    0, 1, 3,
    1, 2, 3
};
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, 
GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), 
(GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

//textures:
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), 
(GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Код инициализации сетки:

```
void generateGrid()
{
GLsizeiptr VBOHorizontalSize = numberOfHorizontalLines * 3 * 2 * 
sizeof(GLfloat),
    VBOVerticalSize = numberOfVerticalLines * 3 * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat);

float dist = 0.0;
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < numberOfHorizontalLines; i++, j += 6)
{
    vertexHorizontalLines[j] = 0.0f;//x1
    vertexHorizontalLines[j + 1] = dist; //y1
    vertexHorizontalLines[j + 2] = 0.0f; //z1

    vertexHorizontalLines[j + 3] = WIDTH; //x2
    vertexHorizontalLines[j + 4] = dist; //y2
    vertexHorizontalLines[j + 5] = 0.0f; //z2

    dist += distance_;
    posHorizontalLines[i] = { 0.0f, dist, -1.0f };
}
glGenBuffers(1, &VBOforHorizontLines);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOforHorizontLines);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOHorizontalSize, vertexHorizontalLines, 
GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAOforHorizintal);
glBindVertexArray(VAOforHorizintal);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid 
*)0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);



//горизонтальные линии
dist = 0.0;
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < numberOfVerticalLines; i++, j += 6)
{
    vertexVerticalLines[j] = dist;//x1
    vertexVerticalLines[j + 1] = 0.0f; //y1
    vertexVerticalLines[j + 2] = 0.0f; //z1

    vertexVerticalLines[j + 3] = dist; //x2
    vertexVerticalLines[j + 4] = HEIGHT; //y2
    vertexVerticalLines[j + 5] = 0.0f; //z2

    dist += distance_;
    posVerticalLines[i] = { dist, 0.0f, -1.0f, };
}

glGenBuffers(1, &VBOforVerticalLines);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOforVerticalLines);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOVerticalSize, vertexVerticalLines, 
GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAOforVertical);
glBindVertexArray(VAOforVertical);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid 
*)0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

И main, где пытаюсь всё это объединить:

```
GLFWwindow * window = initGLFW();
if (window == nullptr) 
    return 1;
int width_t, heigth_t;
glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width_t, &heigth_t);
glViewport(0, 0, width_t, heigth_t);

//CALLBACK
glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, mouse_button_callback);
//CALLBACK

ShadersFor1_2Lab ourShader("shader.vs", "shader.frag");
ourShader.Use();

GLint projectionLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "projection"),
    viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "view"),
    modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "model"),
    colorLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "color");

glm::mat4 projection(1.0),
    view(1.0),
    model_(1.0);

projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, 800.0f, 0.0f, 600.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f);
view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f));
model_ = glm::translate(model_, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

//загружаем статичные данные в uniform'ы
glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model_));

initBuffers();

generateGrid();
//игровой цикл:
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glfwPollEvents(); //проверяет, вызвано ли какое-либо событие, и если да 
 - исполняет его

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glClearColor(0.3f, 0.4f, 0.6f, 1.0f);                   //устанавливает 
состояние
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);     //использует 
состояние


    //рисуем линии
    glBindVertexArray(VAOforHorizintal);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfHorizontalLines; i++)
    {
        glm::mat4 model(1.0);
        model = glm::translate(model, posHorizontalLines[i]);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
        glUniform4f(colorLoc, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f);
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
    }
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glBindVertexArray(VAOforVertical);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVerticalLines; i++)
    {
        glm::mat4 model(1.0);
        model = glm::translate(model, posVerticalLines[i]);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
        glUniform4f(colorLoc, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f);
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
    }
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < vectorOfPrimitives.size(); i++)
    {
        glm::mat4 model(1.0);
        model = glm::translate(model, vectorOfPrimitives[i].position);
        model = glm::rotate(model, (GLfloat)glfwGetTime() * 
vectorOfPrimitives[i].angle, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
        model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(vectorOfPrimitives[i].scale));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
        //color:
        glUniform4f(colorLoc, vectorOfPrimitives[i].color.x, 
vectorOfPrimitives[i].color.y, vectorOfPrimitives[i].color.z, 1.0f);
        //texture
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, vectorOfPrimitives[i].texture);
        //logic operations
        logicOperations(vectorOfPrimitives[i].logicOpMode);
        //draw
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    }
    glBindVertexArray(0);


    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);            
}

glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAOforHorizintal);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBOforHorizontLines);
//glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
//glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
glfwTerminate();
return 0;
```

И код шейдеров:

Вершинный:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

out vec2 TexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model  * vec4(position, 1.0f);
    TexCoord = texCoord;
}
```

Фрагментный:

```
#version 330 core
in vec2 TexCoord;
//in vec4 color;

out vec4 ourColor;

uniform vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D ourTexture;

void main(){
    ourColor = texture(ourTexture, TexCoord) *  color;
}
```

Более того, отрисовываются те элементы, которые я инициализирую последними. Т.е. если я прямо перед циклом инициализировал буфферы для квадратов - то и рисуются квадраты. Видимо, проблема и правда в том, что я связываю локацию position в шейдере только к одному объекту. Подскажите пожалуйста, если моё предположение верно, как мне передать 2 разные позиции? Как сделать 2 разные локации для позиций? Или как обойти это?

Comment: Если закоментировать отрисовку сетки, то квадраты будут видны? Что такое logicOperations?

Comment: Да, если закомментировать сетку - квадраты отображаются. Аналогично и в обратную сторону. Я думаю проблема с переопределением буффера, но не могу понять, в чём именно.
logicOperations - функция, где реализовано включение/выключение операций смешивания цветов. Она работает и её хоть комментируй - хоть раскомментируй - ничего не меняется.

Comment: glGetError ошибок не выдаёт?